# Zero weak gradient implies almost everywhere constant

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives

Let $\Omega$ be open connected, and $u\in L^1_{loc}(\Omega)$ with weak gradient $\nabla u$.

Can anybody provide a reference for $\nabla u=0$ almost everywhere $\implies u$ is constant almost everywhere?

Comment: Try this exercise sheet with solutions. https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~cmw50/PDEEx2Sols.pdf